# Google Play Store / 3rd Party Apps

Tags: android, google-play

I'm sure I Just don't quite understand the Google play store or being an android developer, so i apologize if I'm misinformed.

I know if I get a Google developer licences I can make apps and put them onto the Google play store. But what if i don't want my app on the play store? I know I can host the APK files wherever then and let people download them but then they are considered 3rd party apps or unsigned apps. Is there any way I can get my app to be recognized by goggle like in the play store without it being on the play store or without it being able to be searched for in the play store and only attainable by direct link.

Comment: `recognized by goggle like in the play store without it being on the play store` Why would Google recognize apps that don't have a Google Developer License? They offer it as a premium for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that only apps installed from the Play Store can get around the problem of users needing to choose to allow apps from "unrecognized" sources.

However, if what you are only looking for is the ability to restrict who has access to the apps (i.e. don't make them visible to just everyone), then you can create a private channel, and choose which users or groups have access.  For more information, see https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en

Comment: But with a private channel doesn't that mean I need to add a user to a group for them to be able to download it? I can just give out the link?

Comment: Correct.  The management aspect is definitely less than ideal if you want to distribute to a relatively large audience.